# DateAdd function in Excel SQL query not working

Tags: sql, excel, dateadd

I am using Excel to make an SQL query (connecting to an ODBC).
I have a problem with the function DateAdd(), which just doesn't work as expected.

What I need to do is to get the data from the last six months.

My code is something like

SELECT blablabla
FROM blablabla and then I have this:

```
WHERE Note_0.Relate_key = Work_history_0.WO_Key AND Work_history_0.Order_date> DateAdd(Month, -6, Now())
```

I've searched in the internet and this syntax is supposed to work, but I get this error message

> Column "MONTH" cannot be found or is not specified for query. (13865)

As if it didn't have the parameters I think it has, which are "interval, number, date", but something else.

Any idea about this?

Comment: What database are you running that query against? (if Access `DateAdd("m", -6, Now())`)

Comment: According to the error it is `Progress` or `OpenEdge`. So `ADD-INTERVAL(TODAY, -6, 'months')` or `DATEADD('month', -6, NOW)`

Comment: I think it's Progress. Just searched on Google "Progress date functions" and found `TIMESTAMPADD`. It worked! Didn't know that the database had to be considered. Thank you guys

Comment: @CristinaK could you please post the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
DateAdd("m", -6, Now)
```

Or even `DateAdd("m", -6, Date)`, if you want to get rid of the hours, coming from `Now`.

Thus, you have to declare that you want the "Months" to be substracted.

[DateAdd MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262710(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: I tried it and I got the same error message, with one word changed 

"Column "m" cannot be found or is not specified for query. (13865)"

Comment: @CristinaKuo - judging from your code I assume that the SQL is within a `String`, then assign `DateAdd("m", -6, Date)` to a variable and try `Order_date> " & thatVariable` or `"Order_date> " & DateAdd("m",-6,Date)`. Btw, if you are using string as SQL, you are in danger of SQL Injections.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Note_0.Relate_key = Work_history_0.WO_Key AND Work_history_0.Order_date >  ADD_MONTHS(curdate(), -6)
```